# Connection pool recycle in SQLAlchemy does not recycle idle stated connections from pg_stat_activity

Tags: python, postgresql, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a Flask app, that makes **insert**, **select**, **update** queries using SQLAlchemy as its ORM and PostgreSQL as db management system. Minimal working example is:

```
import config as cfg
from flask import Flask
from extensions import db


flask_app = Flask(__name__)
flask_app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False
flask_app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = cfg.POSTGRES_DB_CONNECT
flask_app.config['SQLALCHEMY_ENGINE_OPTIONS'] = {"pool_pre_ping": True,
                                                 "pool_recycle": 600}
flask_app.secret_key = cfg.SECRET_KEY

db.init_app(flask_app)

if __name__=="__main__":
    app.run()
```

As you can see, [pool_recycle](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/pooling.html#setting-pool-recycle) parameter is set to 600, so that it can close connections older than 10 minutes. However, when I check my [pg_stat_activity](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/monitoring-stats.html), it shows me **idle stated** connections up to 2 hours old. I use this query to check **pg_stat_activity**:

```
SELECT * FROM pg_stat_activity WHERE client_addr='my_service_hostname' ORDER BY query_start DESC;
```

I don't understand why these queries left as **idle stated**, and not disappear within 10 minutes after the query was started. Perhaps my mistake is in my poor knowledge of how connection pools work. Is there a way to make connections close within 10 minutes?

*Update 1: Here is a minimal working example of my view function where I use any queries:*

```
import config as cfg
import os
from flask import request
from models.document import Document
from app import flask_app, ps_work
from extensions import db
from file_processors import common, documents

@flask_app.route("/files/<string:uuid>", methods=['POST'])
def upload(uuid):
    file = request.files['file']
    file_uuid = uuid.lower()
    if file:
        filename = common.Secure_Filename(request.form.get('name', file.filename)).secure_filename()
        db_file = Document(file_uuid, filename)
        db.session.add(db_file)
        db.session.commit()

        # HERE I DO SOME UPDATE
        while not ps_work.check_file_exists(os.path.join(path,filename)):
            file_vault_file_path = db_file.upload_file(path, filename)
        db.session.commit()

        # HERE I ALSO DO SOME UPDATE
        db_file.extract_text(filename)
        db_file.sooner_update(extension)
        db.session.commit()
```

Is there a minor possibility that my mistake is in using **db.session.commit** 3 times, instead of using **db.session.flush** 2 times, and **db.session.commit** at the end?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, it seems like I haven't properly understand how connection pools work. My solution was to set [`NullPool`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/pooling.html#sqlalchemy.pool.NullPool) class as `pool_class` parameter to `flask_app.config['SQLALCHEMY_ENGINE_OPTIONS']`.

Comment: After passing NullPool class as pool_class parameter would disable the connection pooling.

https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/core/pooling.html#switching-pool-implementations

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a lot of experience with the details of the Pool but the docs make it seems that the connection is only recycled if it is requested.  So if a lot of connections are not being utilized then a connection could last beyond the recycle limit.  Can you describe the usage?

https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/pooling.html#setting-pool-recycle

> Note that the invalidation only occurs during checkout - not on any
> connections that are held in a checked out state.

Comment: And how to utilize them, don't you know? I'll update my question to show how do I use my queries.

Comment: I meant are a lot of requests going through the server you are looking at?  Or has the server been idle (ie. a testing server) for a while ?  If no new requests are being made then no connections are being checked out and so the connections would not need to be recycled.  Or were you observing this in production ?

Comment: @adekability also are you receiving any errors/exceptions ?  or just wondering why they connections are not closed ?

Comment: 1. Yes, I do observe this in production. There are a lot of requests.

Comment: 2. I get this error (psycopg2.DatabaseError) SSL SYSCALL error: Connection timed out]